# I am trying to tune a SQL query to get better performance

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012

It looks like the Nonclustered Index Seek is taking pretty much all the cost? Although I dont know much about this dark art of query tuning, so not sure.

My original query is:

```
SELECT mxmservcallaudit.jobid, 
       mxmservcallaudit.dataareaid, 
       mxmservcallaudit.date AS maxdate, 
       UPPER(mxmservcallaudit.USERID) AS maxuser
FROM mxmservcallaudit
INNER JOIN (SELECT jobid, dataareaid, MAX(RECID) AS maxrecid
            FROM mxmservcallaudit
            WHERE type = 9 AND dataareaid = 'ansa'
            GROUP BY dataareaid, jobid) AS statusdate1 
    ON  mxmservcallaudit.DATAAREAID = statusdate1.DATAAREAID 
    AND MXMSERVCALLAUDIT.RECID = statusdate1.maxrecid;
```

And the query plan currently is here:

```
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hys80JZAS
```

Is there anything I can do, or is this the best it can be?

Edit: table structure is:

[image]

[image]

Edit: using RECOMPILE I get a similar execution plan, except NESTED LOOP is now gone (is that good?):

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJq4fG-AS

Comment: Are you able to share table structure of mxmservcallaudit and in particular indexes and unique key constraints in place.

Comment: When is the last time you did any index maintenance/statistic updates?

Comment: Hi @BarneyL I have added table structure as advised

Comment: Index maintenance gets done regularly on a scheduled SQL job @YannickLiekens

Comment: Wow, that sure smells like Parameter sniffing given your estimated VS actual row counts.  Just for a test put OPTION(RECOMPILE) at the end of your query and see if you get a different plan.

Comment: @JMabee so I did that and the plan looks similar to me, except NESTED LOOP step isnt there any more, I have added into the main post. Any ideas what else I can check?

Comment: Well I always try to pull the pieces apart when I have a performance problem, so you may just try putting the subquery into a CTE and then join to that and see if that helps to narrow down what your main query is joining to. I would also be curious to see just the plan for the subquery.

Comment: Hi @JMabee originally it was a CTE but performance was even worse so I went with the non CTE option

Comment: Looks like it wont get any quicker so I have left it as it is

Comment: I would think a temp table would probably perform a little better

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your nonclustered index seek won't go anywhere because of predicates you're using.
But you can simplify and optimize your query by using window functions, thus eliminating one redundant table query.
I presume you might use something like this:

```
with cte as (
    select
            jobid, dataareaid, date, USERID, 
            row_number() over (partition by jobid order by RECID desc) as RowNumber
    from mxmservcallaudit
    where type = 9 AND dataareaid = 'ansa'
)
select jobid, 
       dataareaid, 
       date as maxdate, 
       upper(USERID) as maxuser
    from cte
    where RowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: Hi @DanRom, so I originally had this query as a CTE but it had worse performance. I just gave it another try and it is still worse than the original query. I guess this is about as fast as it can be so I will leave it as it is. Thanks for the reply